# Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) POD File Explorer

Tags: azure-aks

I deployed Dot Net application on AKS with windows node pool. I want to view files structure in the AKS POD. Do we have any tool for that? or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any tool for this but i have a suggestion: If you are using Kubernetes, dont log to files inside your Pods.

Your application should send logs to STDOUT & STDERR and you can scrape those logs with a tool like fluentbit, fluentd or promtail and send it to a central log solution like Loki etc.

Another downside of this log file solution you have is that if you dont have a persistent volume for your pod, it will use EmptyDir aka a ephemeral volume. This also means that Kubernetes will kill your pod if the node reaches 85% of its storage capacity.

Comment: Nice Philip. we're following persistent volume for logs.

Comment: still, its a clear anti-pattern, like executing inside pods. Maybe you should re-think this, you can also read here: https://12factor.net/logs

Comment: just for troubleshooting in non-prod environment if we face any issues where logs are not usable.

Answer (score -1):

I found simple way to view Pods folder structure and view content of file using PowerShell.

Run below command that will jump to pod and open PowerShell to execute the commands inside pod.

```html
kubectl exec -it k8s-xm-cm-pod -n staging powershell
```

[image]

Reference: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0137733

Please let me know if anyone knows other tools which shows pod file structure.